# convert tabular data (mysql) to xml using php

Tags: php, xml

I have a My SQL database that has some tables. Now I want to extract the that data from a table and have it in XML format.

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = ""; 

    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password,"examples" ); 
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else
        echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

    $xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"; 
    $root_element = "car"."s"; //fruits 
    $xml         .= "<$root_element>";

    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle,"SELECT id, name,year FROM cars");
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbhandle));
        exit();
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {    
        while($result_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $xml .= "<car>";   
            //loop through each key,value pair in row    
            foreach($result_array as $key => $value) {          
                //$key holds the table column name  
                $xml .= "<$key>";          
                //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues 
                $xml .= "<![CDATA[$value]]>";            
                //and close the element          
                $xml .= "</$key>";   
            }         
            $xml.="</car>";    
        } 
    } 

    $xml .= "</$root_element>";   
    //send the xml header to the browser header
    ("Content-Type:text/xml");   
    //output the XML data 
    echo $xml;

    //fetch tha data from the database 
    /*while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['id']." ".$row['name']." ". $row['year'];
        echo"<br>";
    }*/
    //close the connection
    mysqli_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

however, I got the following error.

```
The XML page cannot be displayed  Cannot view XML input using style
```

sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

---

```
Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'http://.... my%20portable%20files/mysqlxml.php'. ... Connected to MySQL<br><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cars><car><id><![CDATA[1]]>...`
```

could you help me please.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking to fix your code considered offtopic here.

Comment: Using `DOMDocument` would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
echo "Connected to MySQL";
```

part might be interfering with the XML output. See, when outputting XML you must output xml and nothing else: no spaces, no text, nothing before the initial XML tag (then your root node, then the rest).

Also, I don't see the headers being correctly output, try:

```
header("Content-Type:text/xml");
```

And also add your encoding, if you must.

If all fails, please, post a link so we can see the output and debug the problem.